# How the normal bundle of a divisor changes under a (fnite) quotient map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let X be smooth and projective, D is an Cartier divisor of X. $\mathcal{N}_{D/X}$ is the normal bundle of D in X.
Let $q: X\longrightarrow Y$  be a finite quotient map of degree d. And q is totally ramified along D, with ramification index r.  $q(D)$ is the image of D. Let $\mathcal{N}_{q(D)/Y}$ be the normal bundle of $q(D)$ in Y. 
Then what is the relation between $\mathcal{N}_{D/X}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{q(D)/Y}$

Dose anyone know how to do this problem or any material related to this problem ?